# Does keyczar python library provide functionality to verify signatures signed using x509 PEM certificates?

Tags: python, openssl, keyczar

I could not find a method to parse x509 pem files. I tried using ParseX509 of utils module which threw up.

Comment: "Threw up"? What did the diced carrots look like?

Comment: You will get better answers once you learn to ask smart questions: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use a X509 certificate with PyCrypto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911373/how-do-i-use-a-x509-certificate-with-pycrypto)

Answer (score 0):

There is [`pycrypto`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) with its [old school docs](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/):

> This is a collection of both secure hash functions (such as SHA256 and RIPEMD160), and various encryption algorithms (AES, DES, RSA, ElGamal, etc.).

And I think your question is a duplicate from [How do I use a X509 certificate with PyCrypto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911373/how-do-i-use-a-x509-certificate-with-pycrypto)