# Reading an X509 Certificate in Python

Tags: c#, python, serialization, x509certificate

I have the following code in C# which does the job I need it to:

```
//Try create an X509 cert object
X509Certificate x509Cert = new X509Certificate("C:/Users/mryan/Documents/Code/SampleApps/bundle.p12", "passphrase");

//Serialize Cert and POST to server
string devString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x509Cert);

result = wc.UploadString(apiRoot + "/Accounts/" + accId + "/certs", "POST", devString)
```

So here, `devString` would be equal to:

```
"{\"RawData\":\"MIICiTCCAfKgAwI...OhpEV23wsm06G2s5OJk=\"}"
```

As far as I can tell, `RawData` is a property in x509Cert which equals an array of bytes.

Is there any obvious module in python that can achieve the same result? I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12921889/985012) answer but I can't tell if it reflects what I want to achieve.

Desirable Python Pseudocode:

```
#Create X509 Cert object
x509cert = module.readX509Certificate("C:/Users/mryan/Documents/Code/SampleApps/bundle.p12", "passphrase")
cert_data = {"RawData": x509Cert}
result = requests.post(apiRoot + "/Accounts/" + accId + "/certs", data=cert_data)
```

Any ideas about how to handle this would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you need to load a PKCS#12 certificate and then upload the public key (certificate) to a server. This can be done with [pyopenssl's crypto module](http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/pyOpenSSL.html/openssl-crypto.html).

```
import json
import requests
from OpenSSL import crypto

P12_CERT_FILE = 'C:/Users/mryan/Documents/Code/SampleApps/bundle.p12'
p12_cert = crypto.load_pkcs12(open(P12_CERT_FILE).read(), 'passphrase')
pem_cert = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12_cert.get_certificate())

# remove PEM header, footer, and new lines to produce raw cert data
raw_data = ''.join(pem_cert.split('\n')[1:-2])
cert_data = json.dumps({'RawData': raw_data})
result = requests.post(apiRoot + "/Accounts/" + accId + "/certs", data=cert_data)
```