# generate X509Certificate with python

Tags: python, java, x509certificate

I am not familiar with java and learning python, when I read this code:

```
(X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr));
```

Where bArr is `byte[]`

I wonder if python could get the same result. And if so, could you give me one specific example? Thanks for your instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/index.html) to work with X.509 certificates.

The Java example you provided creates an instance of certificate Java object from stream of bytes. For [similar functionality to load certificates you can look here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#loading-certificates)

Also, check answers to these questions on StackOverflow:

- [Reading an X509 Certificate in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283858/reading-an-x509-certificate-in-python)
- [Create a self signed X509 certificate in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164354/create-a-self-signed-x509-certificate-in-python)